# browserify - Error `with' in strict mode

Tags: browserify

I get the following error in `browserify` :

```
SyntaxError: /myfile...: 'with' in strict mode (36:140)
```

I would like to know how to get rid of it, since this code is generated via `grunt jst`, more specifically from [`firechat`](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L17), and this mean I cannot reuse those compiled templates in my code.

Is there a way to (for instance) annotate a function/variable to make it pass ?

In case it matters, my settings are :

```
browserify.settings({
    transform : ['envify', ['reactify', { stripTypes : true }], 'babelify', 'yamlify']
});
```